# Third part authentication providers - Branding and options

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, openid

I am trying to research what options are available when using 3rd party authentication for a web application. I would like to have the ability to customize which information is submitted when a user authenticates as well as control the branding of the login.

I would also like to be able to manage how password recovery/reset is handled.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I wanted to add more information to detail what I was looking for. Essentially and am wanting to hand off all the password reset, authentication, and management to a third party. Just like OpenID. However, I don't want to user/customer to have to go to an OpenID provider as I think it could be confusing. I would like them to enter a username and password on my site but be authenticated by another provider. Does that make sense?

Comment: Isn't "3rd party authentication" and "password resets on your site" a contradiction? For example if you use Google for login on your site they will certainly not tell you if any users change their passwords.

Comment: No need or desire to know there password was reset or changed. I would like to have options as to what type of password recovery is used (i.e. Is a secret question/answer used).

Answer (score 0):

If it's helpful still, I compared (5/18/2015):

- Auth0
- AuthRocket
- UserApp
- DailyCred

**Conclusion for me was Auth0**, because while all the features are very similar, it felt the most legitimate, as in it's not a start-up that might disappear in a few months. Now, the reason that was super important for me was because login is a foundational requirement, so I need to believe as a customer that the Authentication as a Service will be up for as long as I will be.

Here's the full comparison story:
https://medium.com/@bsemaj/authentication-as-a-service-comparison-5-quick-lessons-for-b2b-businesses-e7587275824c

Comment: Ironically, after all 3 days I ditched Auth0 in favor of Devise. I just found the documentation too lacking after all and frustrating to work with. There were so many commands that I thought would be really obviously well documented, e.g., how to sign up, sign in, sign out, change email, change password, but often times I had to go to the source code... My gold standard for docs is Stripe